# Check key extracted from JWT against database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt

I am building a new API using Spring Boot. It will be exposed to external customers (outside the company network). This is done through a gateway (apigee).

Apigee provides an externally accessbile endpoint and secures it with Oauth2. When a client hits the external endpoint with valid credentails apigee forwards the request to the my API endpoint. Apigee also add a JWT in header, this will contain the API key used by client. In my application
I have defined a filter (extends OncePerRequestFilter) that extracts the  API key from the JWT by using the public key of the gateway.
I am adding the filter using FilterRegistrationBean.

Now that I have the api-key in the filter I need to do two things:

1. Hit an internal mySQL DB with the api-key and get various pieces of information about the caller (store this in ApiConsumer object).
2. if the key is not found in DB then I want to return a 401.

I have seen many examples online that use Spring Security and code for AuthenticationManager, UserDetailsService etc for JWT validation.
Do I have to do all that?
Since I already have the api-key in my filter, is there a way I can make the DB call from the filter and verify if the key is present in the database?
Then I can store the values in the apiConsumer.

Code for filter:

```
public class AuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {


    @Autowired
    ApiConsumer aPiConsumer;

    @Value("${jwt.pubkey}")
    private String publickey;

    @Value("${jwt.iss}")
    private String iss;
    
    @Value("${jwt.sub}")
    private String sub;
    
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws Exception {
        
        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            
        if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            throw new Exception("No JWT found");
        }

        String jwtToken = header.substring(7);
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(publickey.getBytes()));
        PublicKey pubKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(keySpec);

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        final JwsHeader jwsHeader = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(pubKey).parseClaimsJws(jwtToken).getHeader();
        String jwtType = jwsHeader.getType();
        String jwtAlgorithm = jwsHeader.getAlgorithm();
        if (!((jwtType.equals("JWT")) && (jwtAlgorithm.equals("RS256")))) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid JWT Type or Algorithm");
        }

        final Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(pubKey).parseClaimsJws(jwtToken).getBody();

        String issuer = claims.getIssuer();
        String subject = claims.getSubject();
        String apiKey = claims.get("apikey", String.class);

        if (!((issuer.equals(iss)) && (subject.equals(sub)))) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid JWT Issuer or Subject");
        } else {
            aPiConsumer.setApiKey(apikey);
            //I have the api key. Now need to hit MySQL database to access this.
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Code for bean:

```
@Configuration
public class AuthConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean authorizationFilterRegistration() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(authFilter());
        registration.setName("authFilter");
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public Filter authFilter() {
        return new AuthFilter();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you not using the built-in Spring Security support that does all of this for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You autowired the `apiConsumer` so you could as well autowire a service which reads the DB (or a repository), right?

As the commenter pointed out you could use some Spring built-in support for validating JWTs, then your filter will only have to read the DB and verify the API key. It's usually better to have such things handled by a library or framework, as the code tends to be more robust and tested. (E.g. your code will crash if you receive a malformed JWT, but in a proper Authorization header, etc.)